# Android : Display details of Item in list view when clicked

Tags: android, object, android-listview, displayobject

I am working on an Android project, where I am displaying a list of items for the user. Now, what I am trying to do is when the user clicks on the item, I want the ID of that item, so that I can call upon the Object details via the network and display them in another activity. Now the problem is, the object displayed contain only the names. I cannot find a way, to set the ID of the item, which is hidden, and then I can retrieve that when the user clicks and do the subsequent task. Is there any way to set the id somewhere which cannot be seen by the user and can be used.

Here is the code :

```
public class RestaurantList extends Activity {

    String restaurantList = "http://192.168.178.60:8080/restaurant/listing";

    private ResponseEntity<RestRestaurant[]> responseEntity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restRestaurantList);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restos);
       RestTemplate restTemplate = StaticRestTemplate.getRest();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
                requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));
                HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                responseEntity= restTemplate.exchange(restaurantList, HttpMethod.GET,requestEntity,RestRestaurant[].class);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle("Loading");
        progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
        while (thread.getState()!=Thread.State.TERMINATED){
            progress.show();
        }
        progress.dismiss();

        RestRestaurant[] restRestaurantList = responseEntity.getBody();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (RestRestaurant restRestaurant1 : restRestaurantList){
            Log.d("RestRestaurant name", restRestaurant1.getRestaurantName());
            list.add(restRestaurant1.getRestaurantName());
        }
// I am getting error at below line, saying StableArrayAdapter cannot be applied to RestRestaurant. 
        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                final String item = list.get(position);
                view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {



                            }
                        });
            }

        });
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RestRestaurant> {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<RestRestaurant> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(0).getRestaurantId(), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            RestRestaurant item = getItem(position);
            return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantList.this, Login.class);
        StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid = null;
        StaticRestTemplate.replyString = null;
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="457dp"
            android:id="@+id/restRestaurantList" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can use the index values of the listview items in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set entire object in view and get that object (in your case : RestRestaurant)

```
1. in your activity, implement list - onclick listener:

listview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

}
    });
```

2. in your adapter, add tag to each item inside getView():

   view.setTag(object of RestRestaurant);
3. inside activity, in onClick, when you get view:
   you just need to call:

   RestRestaurant rest = ((RestRestaurant)v.getTag());

so, here you have selected item.

Comment: I don't understand where do you want me to set the tag?? How can I iterate through the list and set tags for each of the restaurant objects?? I will edit the main post to show how the entire activity looks like. Kindly give me 2 minutes.

Comment: First, you need to override ArrayAdapter with your custom class and populate layout using getView() method of Adapter, in that, when you set value, you need to set tag. Checkout this example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html You need to create MySimpleArrayAdapter class and before you return rowView (as per example), you need to set tag the object.

Comment: I checked the StableArrayAdapter one on the link you gave me, should I add the id's in that method and will I be able to access it in the onClickListener, sorry I have never done Android code before, just little confusing, I have pasted the updated code in main post. Can you please have a look.

Comment: You should follow MySimpleArrayAdapter, not StableArrayAdapter.

Comment: You have to create one layout xml for list item, where you set values under getView() method. Once you set value, you have to give tag for each item as mentioned above.

Comment: There is already a layout xml file. You are speaking in Android language, please try to understand this is my 2nd week I am working in it, can you please simplify what you are trying to explain me. I have already modified the StableArrayAdapter, and I am getting error at one line. Should I post the code changes, it would be really helpful if you just tell me in code what mistake I am making. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, please post your code, which help me more to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83217/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-kinnar-vasa).

Comment: I am also there in the chat : but here is the link for class : http://pastebin.com/JASLBekc

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean of where one item stores id and second string and when the list is clicked get the position and from that position get the id and do whatever you want to do with that id.

```
class Bean{

int id,
String name;

getter setter;

}

Activity{
List<Bean> beanList

ListView.setOnitemClicklistener()
{

onclick(position)


{
beanList.get(position).getId;
do whatever you want to do now

}

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to to this was created a custom `Object` which contains both the id and the name which you require and `override` the `toString()  method` of that object to  `return` whatever you want to show in the list so in your case the name.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to inherit ArrayAdapter and in the new class hold the mapping between the IDs and the values.

Comment: I have updated my code, can you please check if you have time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this.

This is mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<YourClass>();
    YourClass yc = new YourClass();
    yc.name = "aaa";
    list.add(yc);
    yc = new YourClass();
    yc.name = "bbb";
    list.add(yc);
    yc = new YourClass();
    yc.name = "ccc";
    list.add(yc);
    ListView mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restRestaurantList);
    YourListAdapter adapter1 = new YourListAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter1);
}

public class YourListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourClass>
{

    ArrayList<YourClass> _List = null;

    public YourListAdapter(Context context, int typ, ArrayList<YourClass> List)
    {
        super(context, typ, List);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;
        _List = List;
    }

    private final Context mContext;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        TextView rowView = (TextView)inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        rowView.setText(_List.get(position).toString());
        return rowView;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Your Class:

```
public class YourClass
{
 public Long id;
 public String name;

 @Override
 public String toString()
 {
     return name;
 }
}
```

And Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="457dp"
        android:id="@+id/restRestaurantList" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Copy paste and it must work!!
PS. Sorry for the delay

Comment: So, I finally tried your solution, it bought me a closer, Just some fields you have and I dont. Can you please check this pastebin : http://pastebin.com/ceRd2dyP  . Also, in my main post, I have put the layout file. Please note, I don't want to change the UI when item is clicked, I just want the id back in backend, nothing else.